# HTML Image Map - set area specific overlay text

Tags: html, jquery

I have an image map . I have set an overlay text that displays some data. This data is set as a value of a custom attribute inside the area tag which I want to display over the card, i.e. the data specific to the respective area should be displayed.

```
<body>
    <div class="interactive-map" >
        <img src="https://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg" usemap="#image_map">
        <div class="card" style="width:40%; height: 10%; position:absolute;">
          <div class="card-body" >
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <map name="image_map">
        <area title="Red" coords="25,33,68,65" shape="rect" data-definition="This is a Red Box">
        <area title="Green" coords="132,30,194,67" shape="rect" data-definition="This is a Green Box">
        <area title="Blue" coords="22,147,74,192" shape="rect" data-definition="This is a Blue Box">
        <area title="Yellow" coords="131,144,197,188" shape="rect" data-definition="This is a Yellow Box">
      </map>
      
      </div>
</body>
```

```
$('area').hover(function(e)
{
  const card = document.querySelector('.card');
  card.style.top = e.clientY+'px';
  card.style.left = e.clientX+'px';
  const def = $("area").attr('data-definition');
  $(".card-body").html(def);
 
});
```

```
area{
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.card
{
  position:absolute;
}
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/woke_mushroom/2u3kbnv9/27/

When we hover over any area , title specific to it comes as a tooltip. If using the same logic I could get to display other attribute's property , I could achieve this.

How to solve this?

Thanks !

Comment: Instead of `$("area").attr('data-definition')` use `$(this).attr('data-definition');` so that it get the current area value which is hover .

Comment: Oh. Great ! Thanks :D It worked .

Comment: Note that hover with only one function argument, that function gets called both entering and leaving. For leaving you probably want another function

Answer (score 0):

```
$('area').hover(function(e) {
   const card = document.querySelector('.card');
   card.style.top = e.clientY+'px';
   card.style.left = e.clientX+'px';
   const def = $(this).data('definition');
   $(".card-body").html(def);
});
```

Will do the trick, although I think your map coordinates may need some tweaking based on your fiddle.